# break is slowing down my loop?

Tags: java, iteration

I have a nested loop which iterates over all combinations of two elements from an array. However, if the sum of the two values is too large, I want to skip to the next `x`.

Here's the Java code snippet:

```
/* Let array be an array of integers
 * and size be equal to its length.
 */

for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
{
    int x = array[a];

    for (int b = 0; b < size(); b++)
    {
        int y = array[b];

        if ((x + y) < MAX)
        {
            // do stuff with x and y
        }
        else
        {
            // x + y is too big; skip to next x
            break;
        }       
    }
}
```

This works exactly as expected.

However, if I replace the `break` statement with `b = size;`, **it surprisingly runs about 20% faster.** Note that by setting `b = size;`, the inner `for` conditional becomes false and execution continues to the next iteration of the outer `a` loop.

Why would this happen? It seems like `break` should be faster, as I would have thought it saves an assignment, jump, and compare. Though clearly it does not.

Comment: is there a reason why you use size and size() ?

Comment: I am using `size()`; I just changed it to `size` for simplicity in asking this question. The array is also actually an arrayList.

Comment: "it surprisingly runs about 20% faster" - what do you base this on? What are the runtimes you compare and how large are the arrays?

Comment: Any timing results below 100 ms are hard to measure properly. Hell, make that a second.

Comment: ^agreed - that is why I ask!

Comment: @Eric @Dyrborg Actually, more like 40%, that was just an estimate. It is reliably 120ms with `break` and 75ms with the size hack.

Comment: To be honest, that are too fast to say anything reliable. Try and do the same with a much larger input, where it takes much longer and then compare those.

Comment: And to be completely scientific you also have to do it multiple times and average the results.

Comment: OK, with an array 10 times larger (about 50000 elements), it takes 7s vs. 3s.

Comment: Ok, then this is worth investigating =)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Eric - I'm not surprised.  This looks like yet another example of "poor benchmarking technique" giving results that are anomalous and hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would this happen? It seems like break should be faster ...

IMO, the most likely explanation is some kind of JVM warmup effect, especial since the overall times (120ms versus 74ms) are so small.  If you wrapped that loop in another one, so that you could perform the time measurements repeatedly in the same run, this anomaly is likely to go away.

(Just increasing the array sizes isn't necessarily going to help.  The best way to be sure that you have accounted for JVM warmup anomalies it to use a benchmarking framework; e.g. [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/).  But, failing that, put the "snippet" into a method and call it repeatedly.)

> ... as I would have thought it saves an assignment, jump, and compare. Though clearly it does not.

It is not clear at all.  Your Java code gets compiled to bytecodes by `javac` (or your IDE).  When you run the code, it starts out interpreting the bytecodes, and then after a bit they are compiled to native code by the JIT compiler:

- The JIT compilation takes time that is (probably) included in your time measurements ... and one source of warmup anomalies.
- The code produced by the JIT compiler is influenced by statistics gathered while interpreting.  One of the things that is typically measured is whether branches (e.g. `if` tests) go one way or the other.  This is used to make branch predictions ... which if correct make the test-and-branch instruction sequences a lot faster.

Comment: But would this explain the 7s/3s difference when the array was much larger? I'll try running the snippet multiple times.

Comment: Alright, running 256 iterations of the code snippet: the `b = size` version takes 66.5ms per iteration, and the `break` version takes 45.9ms per iteration. This is for an array of about 7000 elements.

Comment: so the results have switched... not an issue, then.